# Customize Woocommerce PIP add row to invoice

Tags: php, wordpress, printing, woocommerce, invoice

I have Woocommerce website that does not show VAT, and clients don't want that to change.

I have purchased WooCommerce Print Invoices/Packing Lists.

I would like to add an additional row to the bottom of the table with a calculation of how much VAT was in the invoice using a simple calculation based on the invoice total.

I have achieved this by editing order-table.php but would prefer to add this by adding a filter to functions.php.

I have looked at https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-print-invoice-packing-list/ but can not seem to achieve what I need.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a filter after scouring through the code.  I even added some extra code to reorder the values so that the VAT appears before the total.  If you don't want it like that I will post the solution without reordering also.  I've added in a dummy price of $10 which you can replace with your calculation.

```
function modify_wc_pip_document_table_footer( $rows, $type, $order_id ) {

    $tmp_rows = array();
    $tmp_rows['cart_subtotal'] = $rows['cart_subtotal'];
    $tmp_rows['payment_method'] = $rows['payment_method'];
    $tmp_rows['vat'] = array( 'vat_total' => '<strong class="order-order_total">VAT Total:</strong>',
                            'value' => wc_price(10)
                        );
    $tmp_rows['order_total'] = $rows['order_total'];


    return $tmp_rows;
}

add_filter( 'wc_pip_document_table_footer', 'modify_wc_pip_document_table_footer', 10, 3 );
```

Without reordering

```
function modify_wc_pip_document_table_footer( $rows, $type, $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $order_total = $order->get_total();

    $rows['vat'] = array( 'vat_total' => '<strong class="order-order_total">VAT Total:</strong>',
                            'value' => wc_price(600)
                        );

    return $rows;
}

add_filter( 'wc_pip_document_table_footer', 'modify_wc_pip_document_table_footer', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: CAn I change the order sub total amount to [price]/1.2 ?

Comment: I add in some extra code to show how you get the total from the $order_id in the without reordering code.

Comment: It's added look above in my modified answer.

Comment: sorry, but the price still stays    'value' => wc_price(10) ?

Comment: DOH - I found it - sorry!